# Pandas adding percentage column by grouping

Tags: pandas, percentage

what would be the syntax for computing the percent of a value over the total by rows?
For example,  I want to add a percentage column to my df according to its Item and Name1:

```
Item  Name1   Name2  Value
111   x       a      1
111   x       b      2
111   y       a      1
222   x       i      1
222   y       j      1
222   y       k      1
```

By grouping Item and Name1, the result would be:

```
Item  Name1   Name2  Value  Percent
111   x       a      1      .33     because (1/3)
111   x       b      2      .67     because (2/3)
111   y       a      1      1       because (1/1)
222   x       i      1      1       because (1/1)
222   y       j      1      .5      because (1/2)
222   y       k      1      .5      because (1/2)
```

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks [@Wen for correction!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332098/pandas-adding-percentage-column-by-grouping/48332129?noredirect=1#comment83650025_48332129)

```
In [237]: df.groupby(['Item','Name1'])['Value'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())
Out[237]:
0    0.333333
1    0.666667
2    1.000000
3    1.000000
4    0.500000
5    0.500000
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think that should be sum :-)

Comment: `df['Percentage']=df.Value/df.groupby(['Item','Name1']).Value.transform('sum')`  He groupby two column :-)

Comment: That is fine :-) my friend